# facebook api post user action with permission.request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want post to facebook user wall activity like user watched photo.
So url should look like this

> https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id={APP_ID}&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri={URL}&response_type=code&display=async&auth_referral=1

I am using fb c# sdk

```
 var fbApp = GetClient();
 return fbApp.Post("/me/"+AppName+":add", new {website = "http://thebestofpets.com/pet/1161"});
```

But its will post only link to my object, so how to create link which will contain permission requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But its will post only link to my object, so how to create link which will contain permission requests?

What permissions do you want to ask for, and from whom?

Do you mean that you want that when another user clicks on the link to your app he get’s asked for permissions automatically by Facebook? Then have a look at [authenticated referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals).